# What's the right way to compare two dates in php?

Tags: php, datetime, date-comparison

I need to compare the dates from my database with the current day. This id my code, in eloquent:

```
$posts = Post::where('date', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

I want to retrieve today's posts only.
Knowing that the 'date' field is of type Date, How do I make this work?
I tried to convert `date('Y-m-d')` to string with the 'format' method, but it seems that `date('Y-m-d')` is somehow returning a Boolean, and thus, the method 'format' can't be applied to it..

Comment: What database vendor/version are you connecting to?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/676828/1812355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this to handle my database dates

```
    //Get the database date, and format it

$database_date = date_format($database_date, 'Y-m-d');

//Get today date or another date of you choice
$today_date = new DateTime();

//Format it
$today_date = date_format($today_date, 'Y-m-d');

// Use strtotime() to compare the dates or DateTime::diff for more cleaner IMO
$difference = strtotime($today_date) - strtotime($database_date);
```

Comment: You can use `DateTime::diff()`, see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php which is more cleaner IMO

Answer (score 1):

If i am getting what you want, you can make use of [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. It converts datetime string passed to it to Unix timestamp which you can use for comparison.

If date from `2015-10-21` then the function will return `1445385600` and if today's date from `date(Y-m-d)` is 2015-10-31 then the function will return `1446249600` so you can compare the two easily.

```
$var1 = strtotime('2015-10-21');

$var2 = strtotime('2015-10-31');
```

Then comparison can be made as `if($var1 == $var2)`