# PHP, compare current time to time in a database column, then display it

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, compare

I have stored travel times in a database. I want to display to the users only the available travels (those who are not yet gone) according to the current time.

This is my php code, but it returns "false" as result.
What am I doing wrong please?

```
require "conn.php"; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Horaires";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$temp = array();
$now = strtotime(date("h:i"));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$temp[]=array($row['timing']);
$time = strtotime($temp);
}

if ($now >= $time)
{ echo json_encode($time, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); }
else { echo "There is no more travels today"; }

$conn->close();
```

Comment: does both are in same format?  what is that ? please check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446581/whats-the-right-way-to-compare-two-dates-in-php

Comment: Add to your question var_dump($temp); and var_dump($time);  Also, you fetch many lines from Horaires but your comparison is outside the while, so you only compare the last result?

Comment: sorry @Krish, i am a beginner. I've checked the post, it is about comparing dates. I want to compare times. I've tried with time() instead of date() but I still get the same result.

Comment: thank you @Nic. the problem was that in my database the time type was string, not time. So obvious.

Answer (score 0):

if its in a DateTime format (you can create that by using `DateTime::createFromFormat("format","time")` ) you can use the funciton ->diff to get the diffrence between them. Example:

```
$time1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("G:i:s",date('G:i:s'));
sleep(5);
$time2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("G:i:s",date('G:i:s'));
echo $time2->diff($time1);
```

thats how i would solve this. so best would be to get them on an DateTime format.